# send email with JMS and activeMq grails 3.0

Tags: grails, groovy, spring-jms

i am trying update my project from grails 2.1.1 to grails 3.0.5

when i use grails 2.1.1

i send email like this

```
sendQueueJMSMessage("queue.sendEmailCC", [emailTo: emailTo, emailSubject: emailSubject, content: content])
```

then in resource.groovy..

```
jmsConnectionFactory(org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory) { brokerURL = "tcp://localhost:61616" }
```

because configuration grails 2.1.1 and grails 3.0.5 are different..then i configure jmsConnectionFactory at grails 3.0.5 like this in application.yml

```
grails:
    mail:
        auth: Container
        type: javax.mail.Session
        "mail.smtp.host": smtp.gmail.com
        "mail.smtp.port": 465
        "mail.smtp.auth": true
        "mail.smtp.user": abc1234@gmail.com
        "password": abc
        "mail.smtp.starttls.enable": true
        "mail.smtp.socketFactory.class": javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory


spring:
    activemq:
        brokerUrl: tcp://localhost:61616
        pooled: true
```

then i try to run send email...i get unknown error..but when i delete line "sendQueueJMSMessage(" ...")...." ..that error not appear again..

what must i do ?

i get this error..

```
ERROR CifService - No signature of method: CifService.sendQueueJMSMessage() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [queue.sendEmailCC,
[emailTo:abc.aries@gmail.com, emailSubject:Akyong - Reset Password, ...]]
```

but sendQueueJMSMessage work correctly in grails 2.1.1

Comment: i am waiting for the answer to :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i dont know why i cannot send email..but after i am trying to install this plugin

```
compile "org.grails.plugins:mail:2.0.0.RC2"
```

my code run correctly...

so i think its about `mail plugin`